# Database role in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I've a question about `db_owner` role in SQL Server. Does it mean if the users account in this role, he/she can do anythings on that database? Does `db_owner` role automatically included rights of other roles such as `Db_datareader`, `Db_datawriter`, `Db_ddladmin`, `Db_securityadmin` and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all your questions,the answer is yes..Taken from [BOL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180977(v=sql.90).aspx)..

> Members of the db_owner fixed database role can perform all configuration and maintenance activities on the database

Comment: One more questions, if the user has sysadmin server role, the user can do whatever operations of all databases of that server right ?